# Custom String for combobox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a `combobox` that generates a value for other `textboxes` depending on the `combobox` selection.  Currently my `combobox` selection has two values "**Reject Title**" and "**Reason**" combined in one cell. I'd like to separate but no sure how to write the string?

*Reject Title is named "RejectTitle"
Reason is named "Reason"*

I would like the string to show in the user form as:
RejectTitle - Reason with the hyphen in between
What I currently have

```
 Dim f As Range, v

 v = Me.RejectTitleNm.Value
 'find the selected value in the source range from ColB(RejectTitle)
 Set f = Range("RejectTitle").Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Thank you

Comment: do web search for "vba how to concatenate strings"  ... you asked how to merge three strings into one, the title, a hyphen and the reason .... your example code tells me that you may have left out a lot of detail in your question

Comment: Yeah, I was a little lost there..sorry! But I found a work around. Thanks!